# DVD movies have a problem, data/program dvd ok

Tags: 16.04, dvd

HP Notebook running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS
DVD movies worked just fine up to about 2 weeks ago. Either nothing is shown or just the main title.
Tried VLC and Gnome Mplayer - exact same result.
I am able to mount and use data/program cd/dvd's.

Same movies work on another computer (different OS) and on dvd player for TV.

I looked at the other suggestions but they did not work.

What information is needed so I can get this resolved.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs